# Error thrown when when using getLang() method

Tags: java, twitter4j

When I used method `getLang()` to get tweets in English, I got this error:

> The method getLang() is undefined for the type Status

```
public void onStatus(Status status) {
  String lang = status.getLang();
  if (tweetCount < 50000) {
    if (lang.equals("en")) {
      storeInFile(status);
      tweetCount++;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: You are calling the method getLang() on an instance of Status class which has not such method. Show us some code if you want more help.

Comment: Looks like you are using a Status class different than the one of twitter4j. Look into your import declarations and see the complete package of your Status class.

Comment: Thanks for helping but i'm new in java and twitter4j , sorry what are the import declarations you mean ?

Comment: At the very start of your .java file there are some import statements. There must be one like `import twitter4j.Status`

Comment: oh yes i got it .. i have import twitter4j.Status;

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach to be sure that you are using the correct Status class:

```
public void onStatus(twitter4j.Status status) {
```